# pod spec lint passes, but pod trunk push fails

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to send a library to the CocoaPods repo, but it fails the push procedure.
However, it does not fail the lint check as we can see here:

```
$ pod spec lint GUIPlayerView.podspec
 -> GUIPlayerView (0.0.1)

Analyzed 1 podspec.

GUIPlayerView.podspec passed validation.

$ pod trunk push GUIPlayerView.podspec
Validating podspec
 -> GUIPlayerView (0.0.1)

[!] The Pod Specification did not pass validation.
```

There is no error or warning message. My local git repo is synced and up-to-date with the remote's master. What can I do?

Edit: here's the podspec file:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name          = "GUIPlayerView"
  s.version       = "0.0.1"
  s.summary       = "GUIPlayerView is a simple video player embedded into a UIView."
  s.homepage      = "https://github.com/guilhermearaujo/GUIPlayerView"
  s.license       = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author        = { "Guilherme Araújo" => "me@mail.com" }
  s.platform      = :ios, "7.0"
  s.source        = { :git => "https://github.com/guilhermearaujo/GUIPlayerView.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }
  s.source_files  = "GUIPlayerView/Classes", "Classes/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.exclude_files = "GUIPlayerView/Classes/Exclude"
  s.resources     = "GUIPlayerView/Resources/*.png"
  s.framework     = "AVFoundation"
end
```

Comment: What version of CocoaPods do you have installed? `pod --version`

Comment: This was reported as an issue before, but should have been fixed in version `0.35.0` see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2712 if you don't believe it was fixed please comment on that issue.

Comment: I have 0.35.0, I will post a message on that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned about the `--verbose` parameter and reading through the logs I saw that the key `s.requires_arc = true` was missing.

For some reason, this warning was not shown without the `--verbose` flag.